# CloudWatch not populating results

Tags: python-2.7, amazon-cloudwatch

I built a Python script (2.7) that will check Mongo connections, queries, and replication status. The structure is basically 3 methods that runs its respective checks and 1 method that sends the results to CloudWatch:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import commands
import json
import pymongo
import subprocess, os
import re
from pymongo import MongoClient

ret, instanceId = commands.getstatusoutput("wget -q -O - http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/instance-id")

# Checks Number of Connections Made against Total Connections Allowed
def parse_connections(ret, instanceId):
    # Obtains Connections made and Total Connections Allowed
    connection_result=os.popen("/usr/lib/nagios/plugins/check_mongodb.py -A connections").read()
    get_numeric_con_results= map(int, re.findall(r'\d+', connection_result))
    connections_so_far = get_numeric_con_results[1]
    total_connections = get_numeric_con_results[2]

    # Calculate percentage for CloudWatch
    metric_name = "Mongo Connections"
    percentage_connections_used = float(connections_so_far) / float(total_connections)
    percentage_float = float(percentage_connections_used)
    result = format(percentage_float, '.2f')
    send_mongo_results(metric_name, instanceId, ret, result)

# Checks Response time of Connectivity
def check_mongo_connections(ret, instanceId):
    connection_result=os.popen("/usr/lib/nagios/plugins/check_mongodb.py -A connect -W 2 -C 4").read()
    metric_name = "Mongo Connection Response In Seconds"
    # Parse Through Response

    connection_time = map(int, re.findall(r'\d+', connection_result))
    connection_time_result = connection_time[0]
    send_mongo_results(metric_name, instanceId, ret, connection_time_result)

# Queries Per Second
def queries_per_second(ret, instanceId):
    connection_result=os.popen("/usr/lib/nagios/plugins/check_mongodb.py -A queries_per_second").read()
    metric_name = "Mongo Queries Per Second"

    #Parse Response
    get_numeric_result=(re.findall("\d+\.\d+",connection_result))
    result=get_numeric_result[0]
    send_mongo_results(metric_name, instanceId, ret, result)

## Submit Results
def send_mongo_results(metric_name, instance_id,ret,result):
    cmd = "aws cloudwatch put-metric-data --metric-name " + metric_name + " --namespace MONGO --dimensions \"instance=" + instanceId + ",servertype=Mongo\" --value " + str(result) + " --region us-east-1"
    ret,cmdout = commands.getstatusoutput(cmd)

parse_connections(ret, instanceId)
check_mongo_connections(ret, instanceId)
queries_per_second(ret, instanceId)
```

The script works but I don't see the results in CloudWatch when the script is ran. I placed a print statement in the send_mongo_results() and it hits the method. Can someone recommend what could be preventing the method from sending the results to CloudWatch? (FYI: I have an IAM role for the script so it's not that)

Answer (score 0):

here is the docs for python of how to log  (in lambda, but should be the same for you) http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/python-logging.html

edit:
sorry, you wanted to use cloudwatch metrics... check this page http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/cloudwatch.html#CloudWatch.Client.put_metric_data

you need to use the boto3 lib https://aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-python/

Comment: So i followed the doc. Would i have to call the logging method in the send_mongo_results()? If so, what would i pass as arguments?

Comment: just edited the answer... check that method... I first thought you wanted to just log something HTH

Comment: Well loggings is an excellent idea to see why cloudwatch isnt getting the custom metrics.. but also wanted to see if there is an actual problem w my code.

Comment: log cmdout, maybe there are no configured credentials?

Comment: There is configured credentials.. i can run the put-metric-data on the command line and it populates just fine. Its definately not that..

Comment: Yes, i dont see any stderr.. it looks like it runs correctly but never populates in cloudwatch

Comment: here `metric_name = "Mongo Queries Per Second"` there are spaces... maybe you need a \" there. I mean for `--metric-name `

Comment: Ill give that a whirl in a bit